# List element splitting

Tags: c#

If it's possible, I'd like split the elements of a `List<string>`. So for example if this is an element of a List: ***1 - 12/2015 - 12/2016*** 
I need get from this value just the ***1***
Can I do it with an lambda expression or any other? If yes, please give me a sample code. Thanks

Comment: Did you actually try to find the solution by yourself ? Google / VS / anything ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
using System.IO;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {

        List<string> lstrSample = new List<string>();
        lstrSample.Add("1 - 12/2015 - 12/2016");
        lstrSample.Add("2 - 12/2015 - 12/2016");
        List<string> lstrResult = new List<string>();
        foreach(string curStr in lstrSample)
        {
            lstrResult.Add(curStr.Replace(" ","").Split('-')[0]);
        }
        foreach(string s in lstrResult)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(s);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your solution was the best, it was a good start point. Thaks!

Answer (score 1):

In your case this should do it:

```
var str = "1 - 12/2015 - 12/2016";
var result = str.Split(new [] { '-', ' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .First();
```

For `List<string>`:

```
var list = new List<string> { "1 - 12/2015 - 12/2016" };
var results = list.Select(x => 
               x.Split(new [] { '-', ' '},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                .First());
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm splitting a string that's part of a list, assuming that's how you have your strings and then storing the split elements into a different list.  However, you may adjust this to your liking:

```
var list = new List<string>() { "1 - 12/2015 - 12/2016" };
var listParts = list[0].Split('-').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(listParts[0]); // output is 1
```

Another example (if it's just a string) that's not part of a list:

```
string entry = "1 - 12/2015 - 12/2016";
var entryParts = entry.Split('-').Select(x => x.Trim()).ToList();
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(entryParts[0]); // output is 1
```